# Deep learning, neural network

Tags: r

I have a question regarding applying a **neural network** in categorical data.

1- I have one output which is numeric (`Connection.Duration`)

2- I have 5 inputs, 4 of them (`EVSE.ID`, `User.ID`, `Fee`, `Day`) are categorical and 1 (`Time`) is numeric.

I want to apply a neural network to  predict the `Connection.Duration`. I do not know the correct command to use for categorical data. I used `model.matrix` but I did not how to continue with the new data frame (`m`) which contains the categorical data.

I would like to ask for help please.

```
data$Fee <- as.factor(data$Fee)
data$EVSE.ID <- as.factor(data$EVSE.ID)
data$User.ID <- as.factor(data$User.ID)
data$Day <- as.factor(data$Day)
data$Time <- as.factor(data$Time)
data$Connection.Duration <- as.factor(data$Connection.Duration)

m <- model.matrix(Connection.Duration ~ EVSE.ID+Time+Day+Fee+User.ID,
              data= data)

# Neural Networks 
n <- neuralnet(Connection.Duration ~ EVSE.ID+Time+Day+Fee+User.ID,
           data = m,
           hidden=c(100,60))

# Data partition 
set.seed(1234)
ind <- sample(2, nrow(m), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.7, 0.3))
training <- m[ind==1,1:5]
testing <- m[ind==2,1:5]
trainingtarget <- m[ind==1, 6]
testingtarget <- m[ind==2, 6]

# Normalize
m <- colMeans(training)
s <- apply(training, 2, sd)
training <- scale(training, center = m, scale = s)
testing <- scale(testing, center = m, scale = s)

# Create Model
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
layer_dense(units = 5, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(5)) %>%
layer_dense(units = 1)

# Compile
model %>% compile(loss= 'mse',
              optimizer= 'rmsprop',
              metrics='mae')
# Fit model 
mymodel <- model %>%

  fit(training,
      trainingtarget,
      epochs= 100,
      batch_size = 32,
      validation_split = 0.2)

# Evaluate 
model %>% evaluate(testing, testingtarget)
pred <- model %>% predict(testing)
mean(testingtarget- pred^2)
plot(testingtarget, pred)

# Fine-tune Model
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model %>%
layer_dense(units = 100, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(5)) %>%
 layer_dropout(rate = 0.4) %>%
layer_dense(units = 60, activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(5)) %>%
 layer_dropout(rate = 0.2) %>%
 layer_dense(units = 1)

# Compile
model %>% compile(loss= 'mse',
              optimizer= optimizer_rmsprop(lr=0.0001),
              metrics='mae')

# Fit model
mymodel <- model %>%
  fit(training,
      trainingtarget,
      epochs= 100,
      batch_size = 32,
      validation_split = 0.2)

# Evaluate 
model %>% evaluate(testing, testingtarget)
  pred <- model %>% predict(testing)
  mean(testingtarget- pred^2)
  plot(testingtarget, pred)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called "one hot encoding".  There are functions in tensorflow/keras to help out with the encoding.

But otherwise, I would try to do it up front.  I would not rely on `model.matrix` as it doesn't give you quite what you want.

You can easily write your own function, but here's an example using the `mltools` package:

```
library(data.table)
library(mltools)
one_hot(data.table(x = factor(letters), n = 1:26))
```

Note: it requires `data.table` rather than `data.frame` but you can convert your data back and forth.

Comment: Thank you, 
Can I ask you please for more help? does this code work or I need to change it totally?